# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity - Does not fail, despite being unsuccessful

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

#### Overview

I have a Data Factory copy activity in a pipeline that moves tabular data (.csv) from a file in Azure Data Lake into a SQL database-landing schema.

The table definitions will be refreshed each load, in principle, and so there should not be errors. However, I want to log errors in the case that the table exists and the file cannot be mapped to the destination.

I anticipate the activity failing when it cannot match the column to the destination table definition. Strangely my process succeeds despite not loading the file into the database.

#### Testing

1. I added a column in my source file.
2. I did not update the destination database table definition.
3. I truncated the destination table.
4. I unset fault tolerance.
5. Deleted all copy activity logs (nascent development environment, so this is OK).
6. Run the pipeline.
7. Check Data Factory pipeline Output, 100% success rating!?
8. Query destination table (empty).
9. Open each log file and look for relevant information (nothing just headers per copy activity call).

#### Copy activity settings

[image]

Comment: what's the sink table, auto create or already exist?

Comment: The sink table is set to auto-create, which only executes if the table does not exist.

Comment: if you set auto-create table, then no matter how you change the source schema,  data factory will auto create table/schema to receive the data. there will be no error happen. Only you choose the exist table, there will be error when schema mapping missed.

Comment: Not sure how you set as you say "only executes if the table does not exist"?

Comment: If the table already exists, ADF **will not** create the table. I checked this. The table definition that already existed, is still there missing the column.

Comment: @GettingItDone I'm having exact scenario, by any chance did you find any solution or workaround may be?